# The file was a text file but is attempting to be run as an executable - installing vim

Tags: vim, chocolatey

I am trying to install vim using     chocolately

```
PS C:\opt1\abc> choco install -y vim
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
vim
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading vim 8.0.604... 100%

vim v8.0.604 [Approved]
vim package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Downloading vim
  from 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/8.0.604/gvim-8-0-604.exe/download'
WARNING: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\chocolatey\vim\8.0.604\download is of content type text/html
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\chocolatey\vim\8.0.604\download (746
B).
Download of download (746 B) completed.
Installing vim...
WARNING: Write-ChocolateyFailure is deprecated and will be removed in v2. If you are the package maintainer, please use
'throw $_.Exception' instead.
ERROR: The file was a text file but is attempting to be run as an executable - 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Tem
p\2\chocolatey\vim\8.0.604\download'
The install of vim was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\vim\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - vim (exited 4) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\vim\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Did I specify the wrong package? How can I get it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the top (currently 5 month old) comment on the [Chocolatey page for Vim](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vim), the package seems to be pulling from the wrong URL (see the install script under `Files`) and is likely getting an `.html` file back, rather than an executable. The correct URL is currently:

```
https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim81.exe
```

according to the [official site for Vim](https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc). The package URL would need to be updated in order to pull from that link.